# How do i know which wheels will fit my bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels

my bike is: https://www.giant-bicycles.com/au/xtc-27dot5-2-2014 and everything I have came with the bike, only now the axle of the rear wheel bent and the skewer has lost its grooves.

and I would like to replace the rear wheel with the 12 x 142mm version of:
http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/au/en/easton-ea70-xl-mtb-rear-wheel/rp-

I want to reuse the old casettes and disc break. I was told to buy new rotor bolts, will these do? http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/au/en/hope-steel-disc-rotor-bolts/rp-prod9950

Will I be able to migrate all my previous parts onto this new wheel and will the wheel fit onto my bike?

update:
A replacement axle would be prefered. What axle would work for my bike?

Comment: I'm really puzzled by your statement 'the skewer has lost its grooves.' (here and in your other questions bout this wheel) Can you clarify, or perhaps add a picture? I ask because this might shed some light on what is broken in your hub. Or point to some other damage to the bike you may need to address.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus - the teeth on quick release skewers do wear out, especially if they haven't been clamped down properly.

Comment: @Batman - I just didn't understand which grooves were being referenced, but I now realize the OP means the radial grooves on the inner surfaces of the cam block and adjustment nut.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the Oz version is different from the US version (which it doesn't seem to be; the picture is the same), it looks like this bike uses a by default [regular old 135x5 mm quick release](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/us/xtc-27dot5-2-2014)<s>, so the wheel needs a quick release compatible hub (not a thru axle hub)</s>.

Have you tried servicing the existing wheel? QR skewers and new axles are way cheaper than a new wheel (but of course, thru axles are stronger, so the upgrade may be worth it anyway).

**Edit:** It looks like Giant has a [conversion kit](https://www.amaincycling.com/giant-2014-mtb-12x142mm-thruaxle-dropout-kit-w-derailleur-hanger-27108/p331493) you can buy to go to 142 x 12 thru axles wheels.

A picture of the kit is here:

[image]

Looks like the two pieces on the left screw into both places where the skewer passes through, then the hanger is replaced as well. You can see [this video](https://youtu.be/fdGYLwdeCYs?t=254) on how to install it.

It also looks like you need a particular thru axle [specifically from Giant](http://www.jensonusa.com/Giant-RWS-Rear-Thru-Axle-12X142) due to threading; it looks like its a re-badged DT Swiss thru axle, so maybe they have something compatible.

Comment: yes a replacement axle would be preferable to a new wheel. But what do you think the measurements of the axles would be?

Comment: Take the old one to your bike shop, or just take the wheel to your bike shop and tell them you need a new axle. They should be able to figure it out.

Comment: The most common axle for a rear QR hub would be 10mm diameter with 1mm pitch threading. For 135mm frame spacing the axle is usually 145-147mm long. However, some hubs use somewhat specialized axles so it's hard to say what exactly will work for yours without taking the axle out. Taking it to a shop could be your best bet. They would hopefully have what you need in stock.